Add data to an empty array to create multidimensional array
I have a case where I need to read files and fill up an array with data such that each row contains data from each file. The issue is I will not know the number of data points being read. Until now I've had to read only one file so it was quite simple to do it.
timestep = np.array([])
time = np.array([])
with open('time-series.dat') as f:
   for line in f:
      ele = line.rstrip("\n").split()
      timestep = np.append(timestep,float(ele[0]))
      time = np.append(time,float(ele[1]))


Here, both timestep and time are 1D arrays with size = number of data points.
Now, I have to read more than 1 file and fill it into the same array. In the end, I need a 2D array with shape (number of files, number of data points in each file). For example,
cases = ['1','2']
timestep = np.array([])
time = np.array([])
for i in range(len(cases)):
    with open('time-series'+cases[i]+'.dat') as f:
       for line in f:
          ele = line.rstrip("\n").split()
          ???
          ???
    

If I use append, it doesn't create a 2D array. It just creates a 1D array with length (2*number of data points).
I tried using vstack but I cannot use that with an empty array initially.
I have tried using lists because the list.append function can be used to add a new row and it has worked.
cases = ['1','2']
timestep = np.array([])
time = np.array([])
for i in range(len(cases)):
    if i>0: 
       timestep=timestep.tolist()
       time = time.tolist()
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []
    with open('time-series'+cases[i]+'.dat') as f:
      for line in f:
         ele = line.rstrip("\n").split()
         arr1.append(ele[0])
         arr2.append(ele[1])
    
    timestep.append(arr1)
    time.append(arr2)

    timestep = np.array(timestep)
    time = np.array(time)
    **#I am converting to numpy array here because I need arrays to perform further calculations with timestep and time before I move on to the next iteration of loop i.**

But this makes it too complicated: involving extra lists arr1 and arr2 and converting back and forth from list to array. I have only two variables here but if I actually need to read more from the file, it is going to add an extra list variable for every array I need.
Does anybody know how I can achieve reading multiple files and creating 2D arrays with them? I can of course go into the file and see how many data points are there to create an array of known size. But that way every time I run the script I'll have to change the size, which I want to avoid.

You should really avoid np.append in a loop, this is an antipattern: it consumes more memory and it has a quadratic complexity resulting in a slow code.

Lists are designed to be cheap for growing data while array are efficient for fixed-size data with vectorized operations applied on them. A conversion is needed for sake of efficiency unless you know the size ahead of time. Note you can append all items in a list, then convert it to a 1D array and reshape it if all sublists have the same size. If sublists does not have the same size, then Numpy is not suited anyway since it is not design to (efficiently) support jagged array.

np.append can work - if you specify an axis, and start with the correct number of data points.  Basucally it's the same as vstack.  And slow!


I tried using vstack but I cannot use that with an empty array
initially.

You can use vstack with empty array if it has appropriate shape, consider following simple example, let say you want to get (2,5) shaped array as result then you can do
import numpy as np
arr0 = np.array([]).reshape((0,5))
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
arr2 = np.array([6,7,8,9,0])
arr = np.vstack([arr0,arr1,arr2])
print(arr.shape)
print(arr)

output
(2, 5)
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8. 9. 0.]]


I don't know that each row should have 5 elements. I will know that only after I read the first file.

Marking this as the answer because its the closest to what I wanted. I get the second dimension after the first loop iteration and then reshape and stack it.

You could also do this:
main_array=[]

cases = ['1','2']

for i in range(len(cases)):
   timestep = []
   time = []

   with open('time-series.dat') as f:
      for line in f:
      
         ele = line.rstrip("\n").split()
         timestep.append(float(ele[0]))
         time.append(float(ele[1]))
         
   main_array.append(cases[i])
   main_array.append(np.hstack([timestep, time]))
                     
main_array = np.array(main_array)  

 


I get an error saying append takes only 1 argument but two are given. If I remove the first argument 'cases[i]' from that line, it successfully gives my a 2D list but I cannot convert it to a numpy array because of the error: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

The solution should now work with the edit, in case you still need it.
